# Copy and Paste Rows based on cell value

Tags: vba, excel, copy, copy-paste

I am trying to copy rows 10:12 and paste it underneath for every time the value in D8 is over 1 ( i.e. D8 = 2 then paste once, if the value equals 3 then paste twice, and so on).  I don’t even know where to start with this code so....

Comment: Try recording a macro and see what you achieve? We will take it from there?

Comment: Can you rephrase your question?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this I guess:

```
Sub LoopeyPasteyFantastico()
    Dim ValueOverOne As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long

    ValueOverOne = Sheet1.Cells(8, 4).Value - 1

    For i = 1 To ValueOverOne
        Sheet1.Range("10:12").Select
        Selection.Copy
        LastRow = Sheet1.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Sheet1.Range(LastRow & ":" & LastRow).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
    Next i
End Sub
```

Or a better alternative would be this(you don't have to use copy and paste):

```
Sub LoopeyPasteyFantasticoAlternative()
    Dim ValueOverOne As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long

    ValueOverOne = Sheet1.Cells(8, 4).Value - 1

    For i = 1 To ValueOverOne
        LastRow = Sheet1.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Sheet1.Range(LastRow & ":" & LastRow + 2).Value = Sheet1.Range("10:12").Value
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I attemted to insert the first section of code with the sheet spacific information but it was not working... here is how the code looks in my vba

Comment: @David Van der Vieren You're going to want to insert a module into the project using the VBA editor in Excel. You can then copy and paste this script into the module. There are plenty of guides online to show you how to do this. This one seems sufficient: http://www.contextures.com/xlvba01.html       Then you can run the macro from the the developer ribbon.

Answer (score 0):

This formula

```
=IF(A$8>=1,A10,"")
```

Will allow you to copy down based on the value in row eight, if you want to stick with just the value in D8 change the formula to

```
=IF($D$8>=1,A10,"")
```

The formula will need to be updated every third row, so the forumalu in cell A16 would be

```
=IF(A$8>=2,A13,"")
```

[image]

Comment: What appear to be empty cells in the green area are actually a single space, otherwise with this formula it copies down the value "0".